# Цвет текста ListView

Tags: java, android

Доброго времени суток. **Я новичок**, первый раз пишу под android. 
Понимаю, что вопрос довольно глупый (и готов к любой критике), но на просторах гугла я ответа не нашёл :(

Итак, нужно поменять **цвет текста** в *ListView*. Как я понимаю, в настройках Листа нет пункта *"TextColor"*. В xml-коде пробовал, но ничего не вышло. Можно ли поменять цвет через MainActivity?

Вот мой код в MainActivity.java для листа:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.five);

    ListView lv5 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv5);

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
```

Comment: Вам нужно просто , чтобы в списке всегда был текст определённого цвета или динамически менять этот цвет для отдельных айтемов/всего списка?

Comment: Не врите нам, вы не искали в гугле. Просто введите в гугл **android listview text color**, откройте первую ссылку, и прочитайте ответ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте этот конструктор адаптера [ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#ArrayAdapter(android.content.Context,%20int,%20int,%20T[]))

Напишите свой layout, в котором будет `TextView` нужного цвета, его id передайте в конструктор.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.my_list_item, R.id.myTextView, names);
```

Answer (score 2):

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rl"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:background="#fbf9ea"
    >
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Get reference of widgets from XML layout
        final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);

        // Initializing a new String Array
        String[] fruits = new String[] {
                "African mango",
                "Ambarella",
                "American Black Elderberry",
                "Ackee",
                "American persimmon",
                "Babaco"
        };

        // Create a List from String Array elements
        List<String> fruits_list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(fruits));

        // Create an ArrayAdapter from List
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>
                (this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fruits_list){
            @Override
            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                // Get the Item from ListView
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

                // Initialize a TextView for ListView each Item
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

                // Set the text color of TextView (ListView Item)
                tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);

                // Generate ListView Item using TextView
                return view;
            }
        };

        // DataBind ListView with items from ArrayAdapter
        lv.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

здесь  `tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);` - цвет текста, вместо RED можно задать другой нужный цвет.